# variable with the highest number of value

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find the day with the most number of values using the variables shown below. I already calculated all the games for each day as shown below. Anyone know a way to do so in a simple way?

```
Dim Mon As Integer, Tue As Integer, Wed As Integer, Thu As Integer, Fri As Integer, Sat As Integer, Sun As Integer
Dim row As Integer, col As Integer
Mon = 0
Tue = 0
Wed = 0
Thu = 0
Fri = 0
Sat = 0
Sun = 0

'Find the no of games for each day
For row = 4 To 85
    For col = 5 To 40
        If Cells(3, col).Value = "Date" Then
            Select Case Left(Cells(row, col).Value, 3)
                Case "Mon"
                    Mon = Mon + 1
                Case "Tue"
                    Tue = Tue + 1
                Case "Wed"
                    Wed = Wed + 1
                Case "Thu"
                    Thu = Thu + 1
                Case "Fri"
                    Fri = Fri + 1
                Case "Sat"
                    Sat = Sat + 1
                Case "Sun"
                    Sun = Sun + 1
            End Select
        End If
    Next
Next
    
'Find which day has the most games
???

MsgBox "BC played the most number of games on " + ??? + "."
```

Answer (score 2):

```vb
Dim counts(1 To 7) As Long
Dim row As Long, col As Long, index As Long
Dim max_index As Long, max_count As Long

Dim day_names As Variant
day_names = Array("Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun")

For row = 4 To 84
  For col = 5 To 40
    If Cells(3, col).Value = "Date" Then
      index = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Left(Cells(row, col).Value, 3), day_names, 0)
      counts(index) = counts(index) + 1
      
      If counts(index) > max_count Then
        max_count = counts(index)
        max_index = index
      End If
    End If
  Next
Next

If max_index = 0 Then
  MsgBox "BC played no games"
Else
  MsgBox "BC played the most number of games on " & day_names(max_index - 1)
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Kvp (a more powerful version of a Scripting.Dictionary) and my Lib library, both of which  I  developed for 'Advent of Code' puzzles

```
    Dim myKvp As Kvp
    Set myKvp = Kvp.Make.AddbyKeyFromArrays(Split("Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun"), Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
    
    Dim myRow As Long
    For myRow = 4 To 85
    
        Dim myCol As Long
        For myCol = 5 To 40
        
            If Cells(3, myCol).Value = "Date" Then  ' Cells should be qualified with workbook.worksheet
            
                myKvp.Inc VBA.Left$(Cells(myRow, myCol).Value, 3)
                
            End If
            
        Next
        
    Next
    
    MsgBox Fmt.Txt("BC played the most number of games on {0}", myKvp.IntMaxMin.GetLast.GetFirst.Value)
```